# Not able to connect to the database locally which is created from docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to run this postgis container using docker image https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis and then connect to it locally with postgres client.

```
PS>docker run --name some-postgis -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -p 5432:5432 -d postgis/postgis
ca97ca655a2c913cf7eb668b87b43a9ff50116687e2d186407f2b21a3292af9d
PS>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ca97ca655a2c        postgis/postgis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   some-postgis
PS>
```

But I am not able to connect to it and getting error as shown in the screenshot below. Not sure what is wrong here as I already exposed the port.

[image]

When I login to the container I see postgres database but nothing really in Access Priviledges section.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you can try `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` as host instead of `localhost`? I thought these are *almost* the same thing, but still can make a difference.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work

Comment: Ok, too bad. Perhaps a good thing to add that (and other attempts) to your question under a "What I've tried section".

Comment: I just tried your `docker run` command and could succesfully connect to it via DBeaver 21.1.3 with the exact same settings as in your screenshot, except for one minor detail: my local client says "PostgreSQL Binaires" instead of "PostgreSQL 10". Perhaps a typo in the password field?

Comment: that's strange. I checked in dbeaver and pgadmin but same issue

Comment: Not sure why but I had to change the host port to make it work.

Comment: Strange indeed, perhaps the host port was in use by another process. Feel free to make that an answer though as it can help future visitors.